# how do i stop the while function from looping and go onto the next condition

Tags: python

```
def guess(n):
import random
x = random.randint(1,1000000)
while n != x:
    if n < x:
        print("Too Low, Try Again")       
    elif n > x:
        print("Too High, Try Again")
if n == x :
    print("Congrats")
    again = print(input(str("Play Again Y/N?: ")))
    if again == Y:
        n = print(input(str("Input Number 'n': ")))
        print(guess(n))
    elif again == N:
        print("Goodbye")
```

How do i make the while loops stop looping if the condition is matched and move onto the next condition that i have stated. Thank you!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: [break statement](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: FYI your statements need to be indented to be part of the def. Add two spaces to the first level such as the while and those in it. Also your i n==x should be an else on the same indentation as your elif: with further indentation below it.

Comment: Your `if` statement is not inside your `while` (look at the indentation), so the input statements that get the user's guess cannot be executed until after the `while` loop has exited. Also, your entire function is similarly “underindented” and the `import` shouldn't be inside the function (not that it is, really, owing to the underindentation).

Comment: the indents didnt come out when i copy and pasted it

Comment: I'd also get the "play again" logic out of the function..

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`break`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) statement (it terminates the nearest enclosing loop), e.g.

```
if n < x:
    print("Too Low, Try Again")       
elif n > x:
    print("Too High, Try Again")
else:
    break
```

Comment: If you put this in the while loop is still going to be an infinite loop (unles `x==n`) because neither `x` nor `n` change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a new input to change `n`. In your `while` statement, n is never redefined.

Try:

```
def guess(n):
import random
x = random.randint(1,1000000)
while n != x:
    if n < x:
        print("Too Low, Try Again")       
    elif n > x:
        print("Too High, Try Again")
    n =  print(input(str("Input Number 'n': ")))
```

and if you want to stop the loop... Use `break`

```
if my_condition:
    break
```

will stop your loop. It also works with for loops.

But asking for a new value of `n` will result, when `x ==n`, to end your `while` statement.

Comment: The intention is clearly for `n` to be guessed anew each time it is not guessed correctly, not incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can exit a loop early using `break`.  I am not sure what you mean by "the next condition", but after a normal "break" excution will just start immediately after the loop.  Python also has a nice construct where you can put an "else" clause after the loop which run only if the Loop exits normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like this:

```
import random


def guess():
    x = random.randint(1,1000000)
    n = x + 1  # make sure we get into the loop

    while n != x:
        n = input(str("Input Number 'n': "))
        if n < x:
            print("Too Low, Try Again")       
        elif n > x:
            print("Too High, Try Again")
        else:
            print("Congrats")
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        guess()
        again = input(str("Play Again Y/N?: ") == 'N'

        if not again:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated,your indentation is incorrect for the statement "while..." and also for the "if x==n" .Move it to two tabs to the right,as you want to run the loop till the player wants to play the game.In your given code, the loop is running where there is no increment in x .Now regarding the break condition you can try something like this.

```
    else:
       print("Goodbye")
       break
```